# Choosing Partitions When Proving Integrability

Tags: calculus, integration

When I am trying to prove a function is integrable, is there a trick to choosing the partition that will work? I see that sometimes epsilon is used and sometimes delta is used but which version shall I choose in different scenarios?

(Aside: I usually use the fact that $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$ as my proof)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, it depends on the function; but the general idea is this: your condition $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$ can be written as $\sum_{i = 1}^n(M_i - m_i) \Delta x_i< \epsilon$. You want to make the LHS small, which you can do by either making $M_i - m_i$ small or $\delta x_i$ small. So if there are intervals over which you know a strong thing about the function (such as it's uniformly continuous there) you want to create the partition so that it takes advantage of that. This would qualify as making $M_i - m_i$ small.

In the remaining intervals, where the function is more crazy, you can just make the $\Delta x_i$ small. You can see an example of this in Rudin's proof that composition of a continuous function with an integrable function is integrable.